# WordPress: How can I disable the footer of all pages

Tags: wordpress

I want to disable the footer of every page in WordPress, how can I do that?

[image]

Rafael

Comment: Do you know about php css html? You have to remove it from footer.php file i think

Comment: I didn't find any footer.php in the site directory, nor wp-footer.php.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the theme. Look in /wp-content/themes/[your activated theme] folder. What theme are you using? There you should find template files for pages, single posts, post archives, header, footer, and more. The easiest way would be to edit the footer.php so that it is empty. Ideally, you'd make a child theme of the active theme and only include the files needed to create the child theme and the ones you were changing.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 0):

The following may work:

```
add_action('get_footer', function(){
    ob_start(function($buffer){
        return preg_replace('#<footer.+</footer>#', '', $buffer);
    });
});
```

The action 'get_footer' is called before the footer template file is loaded and causes PHP to buffer the output of the footer template. When the script ends the callback of ob_start() will be called and it will remove the footer from the output buffer. This of course assumes the footer is bracketed by `<footer>` and `</footer>` which is standard practice.